# Compile errors when importing ArduDroid to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-import

Im importing this old ArduDroid project (https://github.com/xgxzatx/ArduDroid) into Android Studio 1.5.1.  At first I got an unrecoverable error due to the `ActionBarSherlock` library and Android Studio wouldn't even import the project.  I followed a post that suggested commenting out the call in `project.properties` for that library and then importing, so I did and the project imported successfully into Android Studio.  Then I downloaded the `ActionBarSherlock` folder and put that into my project folder so it is recognized, which it is.

Now I've gotten quite a few errors asking for a different SDK and build tools.  So far I've tried SDK 19 and the default 22 which I guess installed with Android Studio.  The problem seems to be that the `ActionBarSherlock` seems to be set for SDK 19 but the project seems to be set at a different SDK.  I also believe it has something to do with `ActionBarSherlock` only compiling as far up as SDK 19.

Currently these are my settings:

```
Ive installed SDK's:
22
19
15

AndroidProject
AndroidManifest.xml>>>min:15, target:15
build.gradle>>>>>>>>>>compile:15, buildTools:22.0.1, min:15, target:15

ActionBarSherlock
AndroidManifest.xml>>>min:15, target:15
build.gradle>>>>>>>>>>compile:19, buildTools:19.1.0
project.properties>>>>target=android-15
```

Now I'm getting:
`Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock'`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I removed the entire project folder from my workspace and started over again:

1. Commented out this line in the project.properties using TextEdit:

   ## android.library.reference.1=../../JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c/library
2. Imported the project into Android Studio.
3. Noticed I have a Project build.gradle, Module build.gradle.
4. Did not paste the ActionBarSherlock folder into the project in Android Studio this time.
5. Added these lines to the Module build.gradle:

   ```
   dependencies {
   compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
   ```

   }
6. Left Module build.gradle as:

   compileSdkVersion 15
   buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.xgxzatx.ardudroid"
       minSdkVersion 8
       targetSdkVersion 15
   }
7. Left AndroidManifest.xml with min=8 and target=15

However when I run the app on my phone I just get a blank screen with a Configuration tab and a Monitoring tab, but ArduDroid is supposed to have lots of buttons and sliders and a few text fields at the bottom, like this:

[image: ArduDroid by Techbitar]

but what I get is like this:

[image: Other ArduDroid]

So Im guessing this might have been a work in progress that the author never finished?  Can anyone else run the project and confirm?